# What does numpy.ix_() function do and what is the output used for?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Below shows the output from `numpy.ix_()` function. What is the use of the output? It's structure is quite unique.

```
import numpy as np

>>> gfg = np.ix_([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36] )
>>> gfg
(array([[[[1]]],
        [[[2]]],
        [[[3]]],
        [[[4]]],
        [[[5]]],
        [[[6]]]]), 
 
 array([[[[11]],
         [[12]],
         [[13]],
         [[14]],
         [[15]],
         [[16]]]]), 
 
 array([[[[21],
          [22],
          [23],
          [24],
          [25],
          [26]]]]), 
 
 array([[[[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]]]]))
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist your comment is judgemental and presumptuous. It goes against the spirit of SO which encourages people to learn by asking. I had read numpy documentation but did not understand hence my question is my attempt to learn. Pls do not discredit my effort to learn.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I too have been tell posters - "Read the docs."  Bear, I think the first example in the docs does an excellent job showing a 2d indexing use.  Your example is more complicated, but the same explanation applies.  It's a tuple of (5,1,1,1), (1,5,1,1), (1,1,5,1) and (1,1,1,5) arrays, which could be used to select a (6,6,6,6) block from a larger 4d array.  Also this is a Python function, so you could read the code itself.

Comment: @SunBear: If you've read the documentation for a thing and didn't understand it, point to specific things you don't understand in the documentation when you ask a question. Otherwise, you invite answers that don't clarify whatever you're actually confused by.

Comment: Imagine the documentation didn't exist, and someone posted the contents of the documentation as an answer to your question. What comment would you leave under that answer, and what would you ask the answerer to clarify? Incorporate the material of that comment into your question up front, and we will be much better equipped to help you.

Comment: In reply to all the above comments, I am pls to state that this question is awarded the "Famous Question Badge" (Question with 10,000 views).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

> *Construct an open mesh from multiple sequences.
> This function takes N 1-D sequences and returns N outputs with N dimensions each, such that the shape is 1 in all but one dimension and the dimension with the non-unit shape value cycles through all N dimensions.
> Using ix_ one can quickly construct index arrays that will index the cross product. a[np.ix_([1,3],[2,5])] returns the array [[a[1,2] a[1,5]], [a[3,2] a[3,5]]].*

[**`numpy.ix_()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)'s main use is to create an open mesh so that we can use it to select specific indices from an array (specific sub-array). An easy example to understand it is:

Say you have a 2D array of shape `(5,5)`, and you would like to select a sub-array that is constructed by selecting the rows `1` and `3` and columns `0` and `3`. You can use  `np.ix_` to create a (index) mesh so as to be able to select the sub-array as follows in the example below:

```
a = np.arange(5*5).reshape(5,5)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

sub_indices = np.ix_([1,3],[0,3])
(array([[1],
       [3]]), array([[0, 3]]))

a[sub_indices]
[[ 5  8]
 [15 18]]
```

which is basically the selected sub-array from `a` that is in rows `array([[1],[3]])` and columns `array([[0, 3]])`:

```
 col 0    col 3
   |        |
   v        v
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]   
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]   <- row 1
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]   <- row 3
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Please note in the output of the `np.ix_`, the N-arrays returned for the N 1-D input indices you feed to `np.ix_` are returned in a way that first one is for rows, second one is for columns, third one is for depth and so on. That is why in the above example, `array([[1],[3]])` is for rows and `array([[0, 3]])` is for columns. Same goes for the example OP provided in the question. The reason behind it is the way numpy uses advanced indexing for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent simplified explanation. I understand what the function does and how I may use it. ;)

Comment: I get the same as `a[sub_indices]` using (the more basic?) syntax `a[[1, 3]][:, [0, 3]]`. Any idea about the pros and cons of each? Put another way, is `np.ix_()` worth mastering?

Comment: @Patrick Good point. What `a[[1, 3]][:, [0, 3]]` does is selecting `a[[1, 3]]` first and then out of those selected rows, it selects columns `[:, [0, 3]]`. Few things: - `np.ix_` might be used for other purposes rather than indexing. - direct indexing like you suggested would get complicated (and not visually pleasing) when the array dimensions grow. - the direct indexing keeps sub-selecting along each dimension which might (just guessing now) be less efficient. why choose all the row `1` and `3` first and the sub-select columns where you can directly choose only the proper cells from array.

Comment: @Patrick Also add to that if you want to reuse the indices, you have to retype them in direct indexing vs. reusing `sub_indices` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically used to create N array mask or arrays of indexes each one referring to a different dimension.
For example if I've a 3d np.ndarray and I want to get only some entries of it I can use numpy.ix to create 3 arrays that will have shapes like (N,1,1) (1,N,1) and (1,1,N) containing the corresponding index for each one of the 3 axis.

Take a look at the examples at [numpy documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html). They're self explanatory.
This function isn't commonly used.
I think it's used in some algebra operations like cross product and it's generalisations.

Comment: I have read `numpy.ix_() documentation`. It is quite brief. Can you provide a more detailed and simpler explanation to my question? For example, elaborate more on when and how to use it in?

Comment: @SunBear. The documentation is complete. Please indicate a specific problem.