# Remove all zero rows and columns in one go in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to remove all zero rows and columns in one line from the array `A1`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

A1=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 2],
            [0, 3, 4]])

A1 = A1[~np.all(A1 == 0, axis=0)]
print([A1])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 4]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])]
```

Comment: Are you sure the example outputs are from the same A1 matrix? I don't see 2 and 4 in there.

Comment: A1[~np.all(A1 != 0, axis=0)] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure your example works, but given the description in the title - for a matrix `matrix`, you can use

```
mask = matrix != 0
new_matrix = matrix[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]
```

---

you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505046/what-does-numpy-ix-function-do-and-what-is-the-output-used-for) post about `np.ix_`